# Using a UIView xib as a Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I have a xib that is a UIView, with class `MyUIView`. I'd like to re-use this view as a Table View Cell, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

I know I have to register the xib for my table view, like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyUIView", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyUIView")
}
```

But other than that, I'm not not sure how to upcast it to a Table View Cell. What modifications do I need to make to the regular Table View/Table View Cell process to use my UIView xib as the cell?

Comment: You can't re-use UIView as same as UITableViewCell.Use UITableViewCell instead of UIView

Comment: create tableview cell and add that view as subview and register that cell may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UIView control` to your table view cell.  Then set its class to MyUIView.

[image]