# How to Re-use an xib subclass of UIView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, reusability

So I'm a newbie and trying some reusability. I've a class called `SingleButtonFooterView` which subclasses `UIView` and UI is done in an `.xib`.

Now I want to use this in a `UITableViewCell`. I've tried almost all possible solutions nothing is working for me.

Code for the class:

```
class SingleButtonFooterView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var button: Button50!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit(){
    let view = UINib(nibName: "SingleButtonFooterView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    view.frame = self.bounds
    self.addSubview(view)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true

    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.futura(with: .medium, size: 16)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
}
```

Now for `cellForRowAt:`

```
let cellId = "SingleButtonFooterView"
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

            if cell == nil {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
                let subView = SingleButtonFooterView(frame: cell.frame)

                cell.contentView.attachViewWithConstraints(subView)
                let _ = subView.viewLoadedFromNibAttached(name: cellId)
            }

            return cell
```

and in `viewDidLoad()` of my VC class.

`tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SingleButtonFooterView", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SingleButtonFooterView")`

> **In short**
>   -> *I want to use a UIView class (UI done using interface builder -> .xib) in a UITableViewCell*

Comment: what is it in `attachViewWithConstraints`

Comment: yep, I forgot to add that snippet infact I'll share the SO answer from where I've been taking help, it basically has all the snippets, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851892/nib-file-loaded-uiview-in-uitableviewcell-does-not-stretch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015324/using-a-uiview-xib-as-a-table-view-cell/57020305#57020305

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ElTomato but in my case `tableview` rendering is done all the way programmatically. Also the post shared by you, doesn't really goes with the question asked by me. =)

Answer (score 1):

If I can suggest you something just do it "by the book".

Create a custom cell and `.xib`. Then you can do whatever you want with the `UIView`s (remember that you can create your own class and put it into xib by changing the class here:  [image: Where you change class of the UIView]

Having `awakeFromNib` and `Init` in one class it's somehow a code smell because either you use `.xib` or `code` to create a view.

Remember that adding subviews from the VC it's always risky because you need to take care of recycle, what means that this subview may stay and be not wanted unless you handle this situation.

Remember about `prepareForReuse()` to handle cells' recycle.

Comment: Actually I've already designed the UI in the `.xib` which inherits from `UIView`. Now as per the UI of the product, The UI in the `.xib` is basically used in some other screen as well. Now obviously why would I be re-designing it since I've already Designed it.? and the other screen has a `UITableView`...

Comment: @YashBedi could you rephrase your comment? It is hardly understandable

Comment: ok, Let me put it this way. I want to use a UIView class (UI done using interface builder -> `.xib`) in a UITableViewCell.

Comment: @YashBedi my post above answers your question. Again, make a simple UIView in the `.xib` and attach it to cell. Next, change class of this UIView which you attached to the cell and it is ready to go. Just don't use awake from nib method. It is going to be used from  `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` Here is followup:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386339/what-exactly-is-init-coder-adecoder

Comment: I really appreciate you taking out time to write the answer. But it doesn't answer my question at all. And on top of it your explanation is really vague, for e.g.-> `Then you can do whatever you want with the...` ? **If you can write a working solution or if you think your code will work or if you really know the Answer to a question asked on SO** please then you should post your answer, else always prefer comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here:

1)
`Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(name, owner: self, options: nil)` in `viewLoadedFromNibAttached` (if you use the exact same code from the other question)
and you have the same nib load in `commonInit`.
You have to decide where to put it, IMO you can get rid of

```
    let subView = SingleButtonFooterView(frame: cell.frame)
    cell.contentView.attachViewWithConstraints(subView)
    let _ = subView.viewLoadedFromNibAttached(name: cellId)
```

and put that part in the cell (this way you can easily maintain the livecycle of the `SingleButtonFooterView`

2) Guess: the File owner of the xib is empty or using wrong class, that's why `commonInit` and `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` are causing [infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455521/endless-recursive-calls-to-initwithcoder-when-instantiating-xib-in-storyboard)

EDIT:

Step 1: subclass `UITableViewCell`, lets call it `SingleButtonCell`

Step 2: custom view (`SingleButtonFooterView` in your case). NOTE! File's owner should be the class itself -> `SingleButtonFooterView`

```
 @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        loadXib()
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        loadXib()
    }

    private func loadXib() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: type(of: self)), owner: self, options: nil)

        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = bounds
    }
```

This is what I use to load views from .xib. `contentView` is the outlet of the main view in the .xib file

Step 3: Two options here:

- **Option 3.1:** (easier to maintain IMO)

  With the `SingleButtonCell` you create it's own .xib file
- 3.1.1: Add view in the cell's xib (`SingleButtonCell.xib`) and change it's class to `SingleButtonFooterView`
- **Option 3.2:** Do not create cell xib. Instead instantiate the view (`SingleButtonFooterView`) inside the cell and add it as subview (add constraints if you want). Here you have to be careful where to instantiate the view, because there is a chance to add it multiple times

Comment: before all the above, can you suggest that how should I register the cell for it.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is that `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` never returns nil. So the code in your nil-check will never be called. You may be thinking of the "old" `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` which can return nil and can be used similar to how you do.

Since it's never nil, you need an additional parameter, say "hasBeenInitialized" to keep track of if you have added your custom UIView yet or not.

```
// In loading viewDidLoad, register cellId for type for tableView

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

if !hasBeenInitialized {
    // Load view from xib
    // Add view as subview to cell contentview
    // Add surrounding constraints
    hasBeenInitialized = true
}
return cell
```

Comment: Thank you Sunkas, I'll try the solution and will update here, Thank you again.